# Basic JQuery syntax: What mechnaic is at work in this small (2 line) piece of JavaScript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

So here' s the piece of code. I'm very new to JavaScript so don't be afraid to explain the obvious

```
$(".my-css-class").on("click", function() {
    ($(this).attr("data-property-1"), $(this).attr("data-property-2"), this);
});
```

There's an element in the .jsp page that looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript://" class="my-css-class" data-prop-1="${properties.propery1}" data-propr-2="${properties.property2}"><i class="clickMe"></i></a>
```

I know the .jsp creates a link-icon, and that the above JavaScript is an event handler. I know that it passes these 3 values as arguments another JavaScript method:

```
function doStuff(prop1, prop2, obj) {
    if (prop1 == 'foo') {
        //do stuff with prop2
    }
    else{
        // do stuff with obj 
    } 
}
```

It all works fine. What I want to know is what exactly is going on to make it work? I can't find anything in the code that connects what the event-handler returns to the 'doStuff' java-script function.

The names are totally different, so it's not reflection, it can't be parameter matching because there's other functions with the same number and type of parameters in the file, it can't be convention based because it still works if I find/replace the name of the function to gibberish.

I guess basically I'm asking what this line is doing:

```
($(this).attr("data-property-1"), $(this).attr("data-property-2"), this);
```

**tl;dr: I'm at a loss, I know how the properties get as far as the onClick event-handler's anonymous function - but how does JavaScript know to pass them as arguments the to the doStuff() function?**

Comment: The code you've shown us doesn't call the doStuff function at all. Is it possible that you have 2 event handlers, and you've not found the second one yet?

Comment: @dave-salomon anything is possible dave. Even the remote possibility of an explaination why you downvoted my answer to add your own comment?

Answer (score -1):

the onClick event is a standard event triggered on click of any clickable html element and is automatically raised by the DOM.

You are hooking in to this by listening on any matched ".my-css-class" elements for an onClick Event.

The jquery syntax ".on" has been simplified over time and allows you to hook into any number of events like "submit" - OnSubmit event , or "load" - onLoad Event

Wherever your on("click", myFunction) event hook is picked up, your myFunction will execute.

Looking at your second point...

> because it still works if I find/replace the name of the function to gibberish.

The DoStuff function will be found and replaced across all files in your site? or page? or open tabs? , so therefore **it must exist somewhere** as "doStuff(" or "giberish(".
so when you do a global find/replace, do each one slowly, until you locate it.

Finally, when you do a view source in the browser, this should either explicitly show you the doStuff function, or at the very least give you a clue as to satelite files loaded at runtime, where you can go and investigate.

Use firebug in firefox to debug loaded resources; the ".net tab" to view external loaded resources and the html/javascript they might contain. (for example: your master page might be loading in an embeded resource that contains the doStuff method, becuase of a user or server control reference in that master page)

Also have a look at this:
http://www.developerfusion.com/article/139949/debugging-javascript-with-firebug/
You can step through the javascipt piece by peice until it hits the doStuff method.
Just remember to set at least 1 breakpoint ;-)

Comment: Yes, I know how the properties get to the anonymous function, and how an event handler works, My question is, how is it passed as a parameter to the doStuff() function?

Comment: The only reference to the DoStuff Method is in the function declaration. The anonymous function seems to call it implicitly somehow. I assumed this was a basic javascript thing, but I'm beginning to suspect something more complicated is going on...

Comment: Yeah, there's one reference to it, in the method declaration. The code that invokes it is: 

($(this).attr("data-property-1"), $(this).attr("data-property-2"), this);
 
With no specific reference to the function. That is the essence of my question - How?

Comment: its not standard behavior, are you using a jquery framework of some kind perhaps?